# Avoiding repeating logging control in express

Tags: node.js, express

I have this following crud backend code, I wonder how could I avoid repeating the logged in control in each web service, thank you ;

```
app.post("/createEvent", function(req, res) {

    // LOGGED IN CONTROL
    if (!req.session.loggedIn) {
        console.log(" FORBIDDEN ");
        res.status(403).send({ errorCode: "403" });
        return;
    }
});

app.post("/readEvent", function(req, res) {
     // LOGGED IN CONTROL
     if (!req.session.loggedIn) {
        console.log(" FORBIDDEN ");
        res.status(403).send({ errorCode: "403" });
        return;
    }
});

app.post("/updateEvent", function(req, res) {

  // LOGGED IN CONTROL
    if (!req.session.loggedIn) {
        console.log(" FORBIDDEN ");
        res.status(403).send({ errorCode: "403" });
        return;
    }

});

app.post("/deleteEvent", function(req, res) {

  // LOGGED IN CONTROL
    if (!req.session.loggedIn) {
        console.log(" FORBIDDEN ");
        res.status(403).send({ errorCode: "403" });
        return;
    }

}
```

I guess I should include the code in an external function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it a middleware:

```
function requiresAuth (req, res, next) {
    // LOGGED IN CONTROL
    if (!req.session.loggedIn) {
        console.log(" FORBIDDEN ");
        res.status(403).send({ errorCode: "403" });
        return;
    }
    else {
        next(); // continue the process
    }
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
app.post("/createEvent", requiresAuth, function(req, res) {});

app.post("/readEvent", requiresAuth, function(req, res) {});

app.post("/updateEvent", requiresAuth, function(req, res) {});

app.post("/deleteEvent", requiresAuth, function(req, res) {});
```

Implement it in its own file and now you have a module that can be used anywhere in your code.

Middlewares are flexible. Remember, Express allows you to apply a middleware for entire routes:

```
app.use('/protected/path', requiresAuth, protectedRouter);
```

---

Additional hint: you can use this to implement roles:

```
function requiresAuth (role) {
    return function (req, res, next) {
        // LOGGED IN CONTROL
        if (!req.session.loggedIn || req.session.role !== role) {
            console.log(" FORBIDDEN ");
            res.status(403).send({ errorCode: "403" });
            return;
        }
        else {
            next(); // continue the process
        }
    }
}

app.post("/createEvent", requiresAuth('USER'), function(req, res) {});

app.post("/readEvent", requiresAuth('USER'), function(req, res) {});

app.post("/updateEvent", requiresAuth('USER'), function(req, res) {});

app.post("/deleteEvent", requiresAuth('ADMIN'), function(req, res) {});
```

You can implement more complicated role logic if necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's really nice .